# jquery each надимая на кнопку добавляется класс к родителю

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap5

Здравствуйте подскажите с кодом

Имеется Bootstrap 5 аккордеон, при нажатие на кнопку аккордеона необходимо добавлять класс('qwe') для родителя.

*У меня почему-то добавляются классы для всех родителей кнопок*

```js
$('.accordion-item').each(function(){
    var myCollapsible = document.getElementById('accordionExample')
    myCollapsible.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      alert('show');
      $('.accordion-item').addClass('qwe');
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Редактор: https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/5trphsb2/1/

Спасибо

Comment: Все неправильно. Перестаньте смешивать jQuery и native JS.

Comment: @Igor не удивительно, если в бутстрапе пример на чистом js написан

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что вы делаете не так - вешаете обработчик события `show.bs.collapse` на родителя, но делаете это в цикле. В итоге они отрабатывают по 3 раза.

Второй что в принципе плохо в вашем коде - явное смешение jquery и js. Если уж начали использовать библиотеку, то пользуйтесь ей. ЗАмените `document.getElementById()` на `$("#id")`, а события вешайте через `$(...).on(...)`.

Далее, от того, куда вы повесите событие будет зависит, какой контекст `$(this)` вы получите, поскольку оно будет всплывать по дереву DOM. Повесите на item, будете получить только для кликнутого. Повесите на весь родительский элемент - будет всплывать без знаний что раскрылось.

В общем случае, ваш код должен быть примерно таким:

```
$(".accordion-item").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
   // $(".qwe").removeClass('qwe');
   $(this).addClass('qwe');
});
```

Вам в принципе никто также не запрещает привязываться не к событию `show.bs.collapse`,   а просто навесить дополнительный обработчик на `button`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordionExample').delegate('.accordion-button', 'click', function () {
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('qwe'); 
        $(this).parents('.accordion-item').addClass('qwe');
    })
});
```

Еще можно [делегировать](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) событие, так будет один обработчик на всех, и при динамическом добавлении/удалении аккордеонов данный обработчик будет работать.

Comment: `delegate` еще с jquery 1.7 устаревшим стал

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо,
Сам разобрался

```js
$('.accordion-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass('qwe');
});
$('.accordion-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('qwe');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```